Wind Pressure on Chimney

I have this question that I am trying to solve.  I will explain problem as best as I can.

A brick chimney has parallel sides and a height of 18m. It has a square sectional plan with dimensions of 2.4m x 2.4m overall and a square hollow section in in the middle that it 1m x 1m.
Assuming a uniform distribution of wind pressure over full height of chimney and unit weight of brickwork is 20 KN/ m^3.
Calculate minimum value of wind pressure at which tension will occur in joints ?
(a) When wind is in a direction perpendicular to the wall face of chimney.
(b) When wind is in a direction of 45 degrees to one of the four edge points of square chimney.

So far I know that weight of chimney = [(2.4 * 2.4)-(1 * 1)] 18 * 20 = 1713.6 kN
This weight from chimney produces a righting moment, but I am not sure how lever arm works for a hollow square chimney like this.
The pressure from wind acts at 9m (18/2) above base of chimney and this produces an overturning moment.
I believe that middle third rule comes into play when tension develops in joints.
If anyone has any ideas on how this works with a chimney like this, it will be much appreciated if you can send me a helpful reply on this that may help.

So reduce the size of the image file.

@SolarMike
I have used tinypng to reduce image size.
Everything needed is in the question now,.
As I mentioned before it will be much appreciated if someone that understand how this works can send a helpful reply, so that this can be resolved.
Thanks
Robert

You essentially have the equivalent of a flag pole or a diving board.  Its free at one end and fixed for x and y translation and rotation about the anchor point.  Apply a UDL for the wind pressure covering the full length of the chimney.  Once you have your moment diagram figure out your moment of inertia Ixx.  The gravity dead load from the bricks will vary along the length with minimum of 0 at the top and maximum at the bottom.  Find the point where the maximum tension stress in the section from the wind is equal to the the compressive pressure from the bricks.

@ForwardEd
Yes, the chimney could be viewed like a flag pole or dive board.
It could also be viewed as a cantilever beam and Max Moment for a UDL on that is M = (UDL * L^2 ) /2. I believe UDL is what we need to find here because that gives wind pressure  per m^2 am I right about this ?

@ForwardEd
I believe for wind, moment of inertia Ixx is needed to be calculated for working out section modulus Z , as Z = Ixx / Centre of gravity
and then Stress = Moment / Z (Section Modulus).
I am a bit unclear on centre of gravity for chimney, does it lie in middle ?

@ForwardEd
I am unclear on how to find point where maximum tension stress in section from wind is equal to compressive pressure from bricks. Are you able to explain this in more detail how this works, thanks.

Center of Gravity, as far as I know would not be required.  However, if you mean the neutral axis, then yes that will be in the middle since this is a symmetric shape of uniform material.  And to directly answer your question, yes the center of gravity would also be in the void in the middle of the chimney.  Max/Min Stress = M*y/I where y is the distance from the Neutral Axis.  As for the UDL, you essentially need to find the UDL value that causes tension.  once you find the UDL you will then apply the width of your Chimney face to it and turn it into a pressure.

Find the formula for stress from the weight of the brick.  Then find to formula for stress caused by the wind.  when those two stresses are equal, that is the point where Tension starts to develop.

@ForwardEd
For this question, answer in my Materials and Structures R Whitlow textbook is 470 N / m^2 for both directions.
I see how you have done your calculations below and got 2 kPa, but I wonder how they arrive at 470 N / m^2  (0.47 kPa) for this question.

What is the title of Chapter 11 where I am assuming the question is coming from?  If its not clear from the chapter title, what topics are being discussed leading up to this question?

It is Chapter 11 Retaining walls and other gravity-dependent structures

Based on the title of the chapter, I would strongly look at the overturning moment route outlined by Ankush below even though it does not give the same answer as your text book.

I can help you with this problem. Let's break it down step by step.
Given:
Height of chimney: 18m
External dimensions of the square section: 2.4m x 2.4m
Internal hollow square section: 1m x 1m
Unit weight of brickwork: 20 kN/m²
Wind pressure acts at mid-height (9m above base).
Weight of Chimney:
You correctly calculated the weight of the chimney. Here's a detailed breakdown:
Weight of chimney=[(2.4×2.4)−(1×1)]×18×20
=[5.76−1]×18×20
=4.76×18×20
=4.76×18×20
=1713.6kN
Moments:
Righting Moment (due to the weight of the chimney):
The center of gravity of the chimney acts at 9m height (half the height).
The righting moment is:
​M=Weight×Lever Arm
=1713.6kN×1.2m
=2056.32kNm
Overturning Moment (due to wind pressure):
Wind pressure acts at mid-height (9m).
Let's denote the wind pressure as
p (kN/m²)
(a) Wind perpendicular to the wall face of chimney:
Area exposed to wind:
2.4×18
Overturning Moment:
wind = p×(2.4×18)×9
=388.8pkNm
To find the minimum value of
p that causes tension in the joints, set the overturning moment equal to the righting moment:
388.8p=2056.32
p= 2056.32/388.8
p≈5.29kN/m
(b) Wind at 45 degrees to one of the corners:
The effective width for the wind pressure would be the diagonal of the square section:
Effective width=2.4* 2^1/2≈3.39m
​
Overturning Moment:
M wind =p×(3.39×18)×9
=548.82p kNm
Again, set the overturning moment equal to the righting moment:
548.82p=2056.32
p= 2056.32/548.82
p≈3.75kN/m2
Conclusion:
(a) Minimum wind pressure at which tension occurs when wind is perpendicular to the wall face: 5.29 kN/m²
(b) Minimum wind pressure at which tension occurs when wind is at 45 degrees: 3.75 kN/m²
Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any more questions.
​

@DanielHatton
I have corrected that.
It should be Unit Weight of Brickwork is 20 kN / m^3 not 20 kN / m^2

You are going to wind up looking for 2 unknowns:

The minimum wind pressure.
The height at which the bricks will first enter into Tension.

When you rotate the direction of the wind by 45 degrees, repeat the process but use a new I and y that correspond to your new bending axis.  In addition the new overall width will be used for calculating your pressure.
When I worked through the problem, I wound up with an answer of approximately 2 kPa

 

UPDATE:
You may also recognize this formula:
Stress = P/A +/- M*y/I or P/A +/- Z/M
Set your stress to 0 and solve
In the example below the bending in the column is caused by eccentric loading instead of horizontal UDL.  The end result is the same.

